# Early termination of recursive iterator block method

Tags: c#, recursion, nunit, yield-return

I have a method that outputs all the permutations of an array using a recursive function:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Yields a sequence of all permutations in lexical order
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of item in the input sequence</typeparam>
    /// <param name="input">The initial sequence</param>
    /// <returns>A sequence of all permutations in lexical order</returns>
    public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Permute<T>(IEnumerable<T> input) 
    {
        var list = input.ToList();
        list.Sort(); // into lexical order

        if (list.Count > 2)
        {
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                var itemArray = new[] {item};
                T[] otherItems = list.Except(itemArray).ToArray();
                foreach (var permutation in Permute(otherItems))
                    yield return itemArray.Concat(permutation).ToArray();
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            yield return new[] {list[0], list[1]};
            yield return new[] {list[1], list[0]};
        }
    }
```

However, when I run this function in an NUnit test, it terminates far earlier than I think it should:

```
    [Test]
    public void Can_print_all_permutations()
    {
        foreach (var p in Permute("123456789"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new string(p.ToArray()));
        }
    }
```

Here's the last lines printed by the test (I separated them by commas for posting purposes):

> 349527816,
>   349527861,
>   349528167,
>   349528176,
>   349528617,
>   3

The abrupt termination makes me think that buffering and flushing by the console is a component of the issue, but the last line that should be printed is 987654321, so I feel like the loop is terminating early.

If I include a calculation in the loop, it terminates even earlier (in the 24... range).

Is there something in my implementation that explains this behavior? Am I pushing the limits of the stack?

Comment: It does look like the console output is being truncated. Have you tried writing the results to a file?

Comment: You're probably hitting a limit in the test runner.

Comment: You can try keeping a global counter to see if you get the right number of permutations.

Comment: There's a very good way to check what is wrong, and that is to write the test properly.
Rather than dumping to the console perform assertions instead, for instance on the number of permutations you expect or that a specific permutation is contained in the list of permutations.

Comment: Thanks, Simone. Those techniques were what led me to discover that I wasn't getting all the results I expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely test infrastructure you are using have some sort of "maximum time for test to run" restriction. Enumerating all permutations does take non-trivial amount of time.

Comment: I tried our your idea by writing a console application, which returns all 362880 values in about a second.

Comment: Moving the calculation I wanted to perform into the console application yields the results I expected, evaluating all the permutations. This points the finger strongly at the test framework.

Comment: I opened Bug #1092929 with NUnit. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I download the NUnit GUI test runner. The test successfully returns the expected number of values, which leads me to now suspect ReSharper's test runner.